# Induction proof with no terms of sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction, recurrence-relations

The sequence $[x_n]$ is given by $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=\displaystyle\frac{4+x_n}{1+x_n}$ for $n\ge 1$.  Prove by induction that for $n\ge 1$, $x_n=2\displaystyle\left(\frac{1+\alpha^n}{1-\alpha^n}\right)$ where $\alpha=\frac{-1}{3}$.  I don't know how to prove this by induction when there is no $a_{k+1}$.

Comment: $\alpha$ here is just a constant (I assume this is what you mean as otherwise you're thinking there's a difference between calling your sequence $x_n$ and $a_n$, which there isn't) ; you just show that the closed form of $x_n$ agrees at $n=1$, and then you just plug in the closed form of $x_n$ into the recursion relation and show that the two match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem:

$x_1 = 1$
and
$x_{n+1} 
=\dfrac{4+x_n}{1+x_n}
$.

Show that
$x_n = 2\dfrac{1+a^n}{1-a^n}
$
where
$a = -\dfrac{1}{3}$.

My solution, a la Andrew D:

If $n = 1$,
$2\dfrac{1+a^n}{1-a^n}
=2\dfrac{1-1/3}{1+1/3}
=2\dfrac{2/3}{4/3}
=1
$,
which matches.

For $n \ge 1$,
if
$x_n = 2\dfrac{1+a^n}{1-a^n}
$,

$\begin{align}
x_{n+1}
&=\dfrac{4+x_n}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{3+1+x_n}{1+x_n}\\
&=\dfrac{3}{1+x_n}+1\\
&=\dfrac{3}{1+2\dfrac{1+a^n}{1-a^n}}+1\\
&=\dfrac{3(1-a^n)}{(1-a^n)+2(1+a^n)}+1\\
&=\dfrac{3-3a^n}{3+a^n}+1\\
&=\dfrac{3-3a^n+3+a^n}{3+a^n}\\
&=\dfrac{6-2a^n}{3+a^n}\\
&=2\dfrac{3-a^n}{3+a^n}\\
&=2\dfrac{1-a^n/3}{1+a^n/3}\\
\end{align}
$

But,
since
$a = -\dfrac1{3}$,
$\dfrac{a^n}{3}
=\dfrac1{3}a^n
=(-a)(a^n)
=-a^{n+1}
$,
so
$x_{n+1}
=2\dfrac{1-a^n/3}{1+a^n/3}
=2\dfrac{1+a^{n+1}}{1-a^{n+1}}
$
which is what we want.

Comment: Wow that really neat! Thank you!